# Reputation reduced automatically on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I dont know how, but yesterday my reputation was above 250, and today without any down vote my reputation reached 125, does anyone know what this is?

Comment: may be User was removed who gave you vote.

Comment: then my vote gone ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed

Comment: User was removed, who had upvoted many of your posts. So that is reversed as well. Seems like case of serial upvote.

Comment: Check your inbox. You were messaged about this when it happened. We explain the exact situation here.

Comment: in my inbox no any messages about it

Answer (score 3):

The user was removed who gave you vote,See your [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1621806/nirav-mehta?tab=reputation)

And for more info see [Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says 'User was removed'?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed)